# Question about try catch statement

Tags: java, try-catch

If I write this code:

```
Document d = searcher.doc(docId);
d.get("latitude")
```

I get

```
unreported exception ... must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

If I write this,

```
try {
    Document d = searcher.doc(docId);
}
d.get("latitude")
```

I obviously get:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable d
```

If I write this

```
Document d;
try {
d = searcher.doc(docId);
}
d.get("latitude");
```

I get this:

```
variable d might not have been initialized
```

Since I don't want to extend try/catch to all document how can I solve this issue ?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Document d = null;
```

instead of just

```
Document d;
```

Though then you have to worry about NullPointerException later down the road when you use d

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
Document d = null;
try {
   d = searcher.doc(docId);
   d.get("latitude");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You do what the message says:
Just initialize your variable "d" with null at the beginning:

```
Document d = null;
try {
  d = searcher.doc(docId);
}
d.get("latitude");
```

Anyway, beware! if an exception occurs, your "d" variable will be null and you will get an object reference not set exception!
Either include the `d.get("latitude");` in try block or check for null before calling that line.

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize your variable and catch exception (you can change the exception name and getting message level according to your needs).

```
Document d = null;
try {
   d = searcher.doc(docId);
   d.get("latitude");
} catch (Exception ex){
   ex.getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
Document d = null;
try {
    d = searcher.doc(docId);
} catch (Exception e) {
    //...
}
d.get("latitude");
```

Comment: d might be null if catch statement itself will not throw an exception

Comment: I know, then we'll have NPE which shows incorrect state of application

Answer (score 0):

You can just initialize it to null, but you shouldn't in my opinion.

If the method throws an exception then d == null, so you either need to handle that case with `if (d != null)` or just scope d inside the try block.

I'd do the latter.

Answer (score 0):

If your catch causes the rest of the method to skip (by either a return or throw statement), or if you initialize d in the catch, you should not get this error. .

```
Document d;
try {
    d = searcher.doc(docId);
} catch (SomeException e) {
    return null;
    //throw new RuntimeException(e);
    //d = some default value
}
d.get("latitude");
```

Just initializing d = null will simply cause a null pointer when your exception does occur (obscuring the actual cause).